# Grails and Amazon SimpleDB

Tags: hibernate, grails, amazon-simpledb

How to setup Grails project to use Amazon SimpleDB?

One possibility is to install gorm-jpa plugin and use SimpleJPA library, but I couldn't setup it correctly.

Has someone experience with this combination?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the compelling use case for SimpleDB?

Comment: Just read http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/#highlights: low touch, scalable, highly available, flexible, fast, inexpensive, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after many trials and errors i am managed to use simple jpa project from grails web application

I have used it :

## using EntityManagerFactory and the JPA provider APIs

## writing few service artifacts was able to use to simple bd features seamlessly

Answer (score 5):

Try simpledb GORM plugin for grails: http://grails.org/plugin/simpledb

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the [gorm-jpa plugin and simplejpa](http://www.overcomplified.com/?p=19), but there are a lot of conflicts between the [limitations in gorm-jpa and simplejpa](http://code.google.com/p/simplejpa/wiki/WhatsSupported) (in addition to those on that page, simplejpa currently only supports named parameters not positional parameters, which GORM requires).
I've found it much better to just use simplejpa and inject the entityManager directly into objects that need it.
Also keep in mind that there are some limitations to SimpleJPA's support for groovy: it supports JPA annotations on grails domain class attributes, but you have to annotate a getter for ManyToOne and OneToMany relationships.

Answer (score 1):

The current release of the GORM SimpleDB plugin (0.5) is a bit dated and doesn't work with the current release of GORM (2.0.7) used in Grails.

You can make it work, but it requires a little bit of effort. See http://twasink.net/2014/01/29/how-to-grails-gorm-and-simpledb/